# Is there any other Data structure to represent Graph other than Adjacency List or Adjacency Matrix?

Tags: data-structures, graph, graph-algorithm, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

I was looking for different Data structures for representing Graph and I came accross Nvidia CUDA Toolkit and found out new way to represent graph with the help of source_indices, destination_offsets.

Fascinated by this innovative representation of graph, I searched out for other ways of representing Graphs. But not found anything new.

I was wondering if there was any other way to represent Graph other than Adjacency Matrix or Lists...

Comment: Another way could be Edge List, also Adjacency Map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was wondering if there was any other way to represent Graph other
>   than Adjacency Matrix or Lists...

There are alternatives to the adjacency list or the adjacency matrix, such as **edge list**, **adjacency map** or **forward star** to name a few. Given this graph (images taken from [here](http://cecas.clemson.edu/~shierd/Shier/)):

[image: Example graph]

- this is the **adjacency matrix representation**:

[image: adjacency matrix representation]

- this is the **adjacency list representation**:

[image]

- this would be another alternative, the **edge list**:

[image]

- and another pretty common one is the **forward star representation**:

[image]

If you get into this **research field** you will find a good number of approaches, mainly **optimizations** for specific cases, taking into account factors such as:

- Graph size (number of nodes)
- Density of the graph
- Directed or undirected graph
- Static or dynamic graph
- Graph known at compile time or constructed at runtime
- Node IDs (labeled sequentially or not)
- ...

These optimizations can, for example, support **reordering of the nodes** in a **preprocessing stage** to increase **reference locality**. There is a lot of work for **shortest path algorithms**, specially when calculating the shortest path in a world map.

One example of optimization would be a **dynamic graph structure** ([Packed-Memory Graph (PMG)](https://www.ceid.upatras.gr/webpages/faculty/zaro/pub/conf/C63-CIAC2013-new-dyn-graph.pdf)) which is suited for **large-scale transportation networks**.

Answer (score 0):

There is another representation of graphs using Adjacency Set. It is very much similar to adjacency list but instead of using Linked lists, Disjoint Sets [Union-Find] are used. You can read about disjoint sets ADT [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

If E is the number of edges and V is the number of vertices in the graph, then Adjacency set representation of graph takes up (E+V) space.

Complexities of other operations while using adjacency set representation:

```
Checking edge between vertex v and w : log(Degree(v))
Iterate over edges incident to vertex v: Degree(v)
```